# How can I programmatically find the list of codecs known to Python?

Tags: python, internationalization, character-encoding

I know that I can do the following:

```
>>> import encodings, pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(sorted(encodings.aliases.aliases.values()))
['ascii',
 'base64_codec',
 'big5',
 'big5hkscs',
 'bz2_codec',
 'cp037',
 'cp1026',
 'cp1140',
 'cp1250',
 'cp1251',
 'cp1252',
 'cp1253',
 'cp1254',
 'cp1255',
 'cp1256',
 'cp1257',
 'cp1258',
 'cp424',
 'cp437',
 'cp500',
 'cp775',
 'cp850',
 'cp852',
 'cp855',
 'cp857',
 'cp860',
 'cp861',
 'cp862',
 'cp863',
 'cp864',
 'cp865',
 'cp866',
 'cp869',
 'cp932',
 'cp949',
 'cp950',
 'euc_jis_2004',
 'euc_jisx0213',
 'euc_jp',
 'euc_kr',
 'gb18030',
 'gb2312',
 'gbk',
 'hex_codec',
 'hp_roman8',
 'hz',
 'iso2022_jp',
 'iso2022_jp_1',
 'iso2022_jp_2',
 'iso2022_jp_2004',
 'iso2022_jp_3',
 'iso2022_jp_ext',
 'iso2022_kr',
 'iso8859_10',
 'iso8859_11',
 'iso8859_13',
 'iso8859_14',
 'iso8859_15',
 'iso8859_16',
 'iso8859_2',
 'iso8859_3',
 'iso8859_4',
 'iso8859_5',
 'iso8859_6',
 'iso8859_7',
 'iso8859_8',
 'iso8859_9',
 'johab',
 'koi8_r',
 'latin_1',
 'mac_cyrillic',
 'mac_greek',
 'mac_iceland',
 'mac_latin2',
 'mac_roman',
 'mac_turkish',
 'mbcs',
 'ptcp154',
 'quopri_codec',
 'rot_13',
 'shift_jis',
 'shift_jis_2004',
 'shift_jisx0213',
 'tactis',
 'tis_620',
 'utf_16',
 'utf_16_be',
 'utf_16_le',
 'utf_32',
 'utf_32_be',
 'utf_32_le',
 'utf_7',
 'utf_8',
 'uu_codec',
 'zlib_codec']
```

I also know for sure that this is not a complete list, since it includes *only* encodings for which an alias exists (e.g "cp737" is missing), and at least some pseudo-encodings are missing (e.g "string_escape").

As the title of the question says: how can I programmatically get a list of all codecs/encodings known to Python?

If not programmatically: is there a complete list available online?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think the complete list is stored anywhere in the python standard library. Instead, encodings are loaded on demand through calls to `encoding.search_function(encoding)`. If you study the code there, it looks like `encoding` string is first normalized and then the `encodings` package is searched for submodules whose name matches `encoding`.

The following uses `pkgutil` to list all the submodules of `encoding`, and then adds them to those listed in `encoding.aliases.aliases`.

Unfortunately, `encoding.aliases.aliases` contains one encoding, `tactis` that is not generated by the above, so I tried to generate the complete list by union-ing the two sets.

```
import encodings
import os
import pkgutil

modnames=set([modname for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(
    path=[os.path.dirname(encodings.__file__)], prefix='')])
aliases=set(encodings.aliases.aliases.values())

print(modnames-aliases)
# set(['charmap', 'unicode_escape', 'cp1006', 'unicode_internal', 'punycode', 'string_escape', 'aliases', 'palmos', 'mac_centeuro', 'mac_farsi', 'mac_romanian', 'cp856', 'raw_unicode_escape', 'mac_croatian', 'utf_8_sig', 'mac_arabic', 'undefined', 'cp737', 'idna', 'koi8_u', 'cp875', 'cp874', 'iso8859_1'])

print(aliases-modnames)
# set(['tactis'])

codec_names=modnames.union(aliases)
print(codec_names)
# set(['bz2_codec', 'cp1140', 'euc_jp', 'cp932', 'punycode', 'euc_jisx0213', 'aliases', 'hex_codec', 'cp500', 'uu_codec', 'big5hkscs', 'mac_romanian', 'mbcs', 'euc_jis_2004', 'iso2022_jp_3', 'iso2022_jp_2', 'iso2022_jp_1', 'gbk', 'iso2022_jp_2004', 'unicode_internal', 'utf_16_be', 'quopri_codec', 'cp424', 'iso2022_jp', 'mac_iceland', 'raw_unicode_escape', 'hp_roman8', 'iso2022_kr', 'cp875', 'iso8859_6', 'cp1254', 'utf_32_be', 'gb2312', 'cp850', 'shift_jis', 'cp852', 'cp855', 'iso8859_3', 'cp857', 'cp856', 'cp775', 'unicode_escape', 'cp1026', 'mac_latin2', 'utf_32', 'mac_cyrillic', 'base64_codec', 'ptcp154', 'palmos', 'mac_centeuro', 'euc_kr', 'hz', 'utf_8', 'utf_32_le', 'mac_greek', 'utf_7', 'mac_turkish', 'utf_8_sig', 'mac_arabic', 'tactis', 'cp949', 'zlib_codec', 'big5', 'iso8859_9', 'iso8859_8', 'iso8859_5', 'iso8859_4', 'iso8859_7', 'cp874', 'iso8859_1', 'utf_16_le', 'iso8859_2', 'charmap', 'gb18030', 'cp1006', 'shift_jis_2004', 'mac_roman', 'ascii', 'string_escape', 'iso8859_15', 'iso8859_14', 'tis_620', 'iso8859_16', 'iso8859_11', 'iso8859_10', 'iso8859_13', 'cp950', 'utf_16', 'cp869', 'mac_farsi', 'rot_13', 'cp860', 'cp861', 'cp862', 'cp863', 'cp864', 'cp865', 'cp866', 'shift_jisx0213', 'johab', 'mac_croatian', 'cp1255', 'latin_1', 'cp1257', 'cp1256', 'cp1251', 'cp1250', 'cp1253', 'cp1252', 'cp437', 'cp1258', 'undefined', 'cp737', 'koi8_r', 'cp037', 'koi8_u', 'iso2022_jp_ext', 'idna'])
```

Comment: @killown: did you downvote this? If yes, you shouldn't, because it gives a programmatically useful result (a set), which was my primary target. How can I iterate over `help(encodings)` in a program?

Comment: In general: anyone who downvoted this answer has absolutely no grasp of what up/downvoting means here and should hover their mouse pointers over the arrows before clicking.

Comment: @killown: indeed; see who voted to close the question. Unfortunately, the list of similar questions *after* the question is posted is *not* the same with the one *during* typing in the question; also, the search with "[python] encodings list" did not procure the old question.

Answer (score 0):

Either install the [gettextcodecs](https://pypi.org/project/gettextcodecs/) library (*one more?*) or just (*simpler*) get the code from that library and use it. Not checked if it works in python <3.