# What is the encoding format of nginx's access log?

Tags: nginx

What is the encoding of Nginx's access.log? I'm trying to iterate through the file but my script [raises an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982513/rails-ruby-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8-even-after-force-encoding) "`invalid byte sequence in UTF-8`" when it sees requests to my server that have Chinese/Thai characters in them.

Answer (score 1):

An HTTP protocol request is mostly ASCII, with data fields allowed to be any octets. See [Which encoding is used by the HTTP protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818122/which-encoding-is-used-by-the-http-protocol) .

Nginx's error and access logs will reflect that.

My experience with 450,000 records from a small North American site revealed that all but one record decoded to ASCII without error. That record contained 4 consecutive bytes (b'\xb8E\x8c\xde') that were invalid UTF-8 but were valid big5hkscs (Python's codec for Traditional Chinese) that produced two glyphs.

See [How can I programmatically find the list of codecs known to Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824101/how-can-i-programmatically-find-the-list-of-codecs-known-to-python) to get a list of codec names for a brute force attack on non-ASCII bits.

Decoding the binary log records to ASCII, with '?' replacements for errors, was good enough for my needs.